# Lightbox won't work when my site css page is linked

Tags: lightbox

I just installed Lightbox on an html page in a website I am building. Lightbox works when only the lightbox.css page is linked.

But when I link my site's stylesheet, too, the page background turns dark but the image doesn't load.

Here is how the head looks when Lightbox is NOT working:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="site_css/sjp.css" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Shenandoah Valley Apples</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining the lightwindow.css document, I discovered it contained a body element selector with rules applied. All other rules in the lightwindow.css document use class or id selectors. See below.

```
/* Preload images */
body:after {
  content: url(../img/close.png) url(../img/loading.gif) url(../img/prev.png) url(../img/next.png);
  display: none;
}
```

My css page had a body element selector too. Rules applied to my body element selector conflicted with those in the lightwindow.css document.

I solved the problem by removing all of my rules from the  element and applying them to a  element instead.

Now Lightwindow works as it is supposed to.